# Can't hide "Preferences" item in edit-menu

Tags: user-interface, menu, frameworks, scheme, racket

How do I hide "Preferences" item in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ol2.png) when "undo and redo" items are able to hide? I tried using (preferences:hide-dialog) but there was no difference in GUI.

```
#lang racket/gui
(require framework)

(define menu-super-frame% 
  (frame:standard-menus-mixin   
   frame:basic%))

    (define menu-frame%
      (class menu-super-frame%
        (inherit get-file-menu set-icon)
        ;hiding items in edit menu
        (define/override (edit-menu:create-undo?) #f)
        (define/override (edit-menu:create-redo?) #f)            
        (super-new)))

    (define top-frame 
      (new menu-frame%
       [label "Main Window"]
       [width 200]
       [height 200]
       [alignment (list 'left 'top)]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(define/override (edit-menu:create-preferences?) #f)
```

Note: I haven't tested that it works, but digging in the code shows that the following are defined:

```
                file-menu:create-new?
                file-menu:create-open?
                file-menu:create-open-recent?
                file-menu:create-revert?
                file-menu:create-save?
                file-menu:create-save-as?
                file-menu:create-print?
                edit-menu:create-undo?
                edit-menu:create-redo?
                edit-menu:create-cut?
                edit-menu:create-paste?
                edit-menu:create-clear?
                edit-menu:create-find?
                edit-menu:create-preferences?
```

Comment: I have tried that one with wrong spelling before, thinking that code doesn't work and keep searching for some more codes. Thank you so much @soegaard. :)

Comment: there is still another problem with extra separator lines after hiding "preference" menu item, @soegaard I have posted scr shot at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236400/hide-extra-separator-lines-between-empty-menu-items)

Comment: @link I have no idea. Consider asking the Racket mailing list.

Comment: Yes, I have got the correct answer there, @soegaard
[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/racket-users/BHFD6APnyyg)