# Hide extra separator lines between empty menu items

Tags: user-interface, menu, frameworks, scheme, racket

Separator lines still appear after hiding menu-items from this link => [Can't hide "Preferences" item in edit-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119680/cant-hide-preferences-item-in-edit-menu)

[image]

I have searched in racket documentation and found only adding new separator menu item. https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/separator-menu-item_.html
Is it possible to hide these extra lines between empty menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separator lines are created in the "between" methods. Those are removed by using `void`.

[image: Separator lines are disappeared.]

```
#lang racket/gui
(require framework)

(define menu-super-frame% 
  (frame:standard-menus-mixin   
   frame:basic%))

(define menu-frame%
  (class menu-super-frame%
    (inherit get-file-menu set-icon)

    (define/override (edit-menu:create-undo?) #t)    
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-redo?) #t)

    ;; hiding items in edit menu
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-cut?) #f)
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-copy?) #f)
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-paste?) #f)
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-clear?) #f)
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-select-all?) #f)
    (define/override (edit-menu:create-preferences?) #f)

    ;; remove separator lines
    (define/override (edit-menu:between-redo-and-cut edit-menu) (void)) 
    (define/override (edit-menu:between-select-all-and-find edit-menu) (void))
    (define/override (edit-menu:between-find-and-preferences edit-menu) (void))

    (super-new)))

(define top-frame 
  (new menu-frame%
       [label "Main Window"]
       [width 200]
       [height 200]
       [alignment (list 'left 'top)]))

(send top-frame show #t)
```

[reference answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/racket-users/BHFD6APnyyg)